# How to restart/merge migration?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity framework code first and I have almost 10 migrations now. I found a design issue and some of the DBMigrations are not what I expected and I want to re-generated the database.

1. How to discard all these existed migrations and regenerate the tables on development database? (delete all the cs files under `Migrations` folder and delete the database? What if I want to keep the first xxxxxx_InitialCreate.cs and restart from there?)
2. What if the database already published to production database server? What's the best way to sync the development database/migrations and production database/migrations?

Answer (score 1):

You could revert to that initial migration

```
Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>]
  [-Script] [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>]
  [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] -ConnectionString <String>
  -ConnectionProviderName <String> [<CommonParameters>]
```

is the Syntax so:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration InitialCreate
```

reverts your database to the initial migrationFor the second part I would just change the connection string to the production database and run the migration again. No loss of data should occur.